# How to find root cause of "NetIq Overall CPU overloaded" in Linux

Tags: linux

It is reported that one of my linux vm is cpu overloaded on some previous time. What is the standard procedure to diagnose that which process or user causes the cpu overload?

Answer (score 0):

Read `man top`, and `man -k accounting`. `top` shows what's running now, and process accounting keeps track over time.